# Azure SSL & TLS error in android application while making connection between azure server and Android application

Tags: java, android, azure, ssl, tls1.2

E/SQL connection error :: "encrypt" property is set to "true" and "trustServerCertificate" property is set to "true" but the driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption: Error: Socket is closed. ClientConnectionId:f1314ef7-64d8-4179-94fe-5b3af42de621

The code is not working in android application but when we compile the particular class it works without any error in console. We are using AZURE.

```
private Connection establishConnection() {
    Connection connection = null;
    String ipAddress = "0.0.0.0";
    String username = "USERNAME";
    String password = "NONE";
    String database = "DB";
    String port = "PORT";
    try {
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://" + ipAddress + ":" + port + ";databaseName=" + database + ";encrypt=true;sslProtocol=TLSv1.2;TrustServerCertificate=true";
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SQL connection error : ", e.getMessage());
    }
    return connection;
}
```